# readlines function to insert text line by line from a file into string array passed by pointer

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function read_lines that takes a file *fp, a pointer to char** lines, and pointer to int num_lines. The function should insert each line of text into lines, and increase num_lines to however many lines the file has.

Its probably really simple but I've been trying to insert the text for several hours now.

This is what main.c would look like. Everything but read_lines is already defined and working. The file can have any amount of lines, tabs, and can even be only newlines.

(this is a homework assigment, so main.c and the function declaration must stay the same)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char** lines = NULL;
    int num_lines = 0;
    FILE* fp = validate_input(argc, argv);
    read_lines(fp, &lines, &num_lines);
    print_lines(lines, num_lines);
    free_lines(lines, num_lines);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

This is one of my attempts at trying to append lines, but I couldn't figure it out.

read_lines.c

```
void read_lines(FILE *fp, char ***lines, int *num_lines) {
    int i;
    int N = 0;
    char s[200];
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        while(fgets(s, 200, fp)!=NULL){N++;}
        char strings[50][200];

        rewind(fp);
        fgets(s, 200, fp);
        strcpy(lines[i],s);
    }

}
```

I'd appreciate any help at solving this, thanks.

Comment: You never allocated space for `lines`.

Comment: You need to call `malloc`, `realloc`, etc. to allocate your dynamic memory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically allocate the memory for each line as you read them. This is done with the [malloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) and [realloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) functions. `malloc` to allocate memory and `realloc` to resize the allocation.

The below code should do what you want (I haven't extensively tested it), but omits error checking that would be good practice.

```
void read_lines (FILE *fp, char ***lines, int *num_lines) {
    // Initialize you number of lines variable
    *num_lines = 0;

    //Initialize the lines pointer
    // NO ERROR CHECKING DONE HERE
    *lines = malloc(sizeof(char*));

    // create a fixed size buffer for reading from file
    char s[200];

    // Read from the file using fgets
    while (fgets(s, 200, fp) != NULL) {
        // THIS CODE ASSUMES ALL LINES ARE LESS THAN 200 CHARACTERS
        // The memory to hold the line of text needs to be allocated
        int length = strlen(s);
        // Ensure there is space for the terminating null character
        (*lines)[*num_lines] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
        // The line needs to be copied from the buffer to the allocated memory
        strcpy((*lines)[*num_lines], s);

        // increment number of lines variable
        *num_lines++;

        // allocate space for another line in advance
        *lines = realloc(*lines, sizeof(char*) * ((*num_lines) + 1));
    }

    // There will be an extra line pointer allocated in the loop
    // Shrink the allocation to the appropriate size
    *lines = realloc(*lines, sizeof(char*) * (*num_lines));
}
```

Comment: There is a precedence problem in `*lines[*num_lines]`: you should write `(*lines)[*num_lines]` instead. The last call to `realloc` should use `num_lines` instead of `(num_lines + 1)`, but it may fail if the file is empty. Instead of reallocating the array, you could just store a null pointer in `(*lines)[*num_lines]`.

Comment: ```sizeof(char*) * (num_lines + 1))``` Clion gives me the error "Invalid operands to binary expression(unsigned long and int*)

Comment: @chqrlie good catch, I missed that, it should be fixed now. I left the final realloc in, I assume there are specific requirements for an empty file that will have to be implemented along with other error checking